# Create groupings on data

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I have input data like this:

[image: Input]

The output I require is grouping all the elements and giving distinct customers and total sales for each group. I have tried cross matrix, group by, and cube functions until now, but however, I am not getting the desired results.

Output expected:

[image: Output]

Any help will highly appreciated.

Comment: We need your attempt to solve this problem - code that did not lead to the desired result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.